# Javax mail api: getting part.getdispotion()= null even if attachment in present

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

I am facing this issue after using the  mac mailing service.
able to read attachments  if  I use outlook or gmail.

piece of code where  I am reading the attachment from mail.

```
if (contentType.contains("multipart"))
        {
            Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            int partCount = multiPart.getCount();                                       

            for (int j = 0; j < partCount; j++)
            {
                BodyPart part = multiPart.getBodyPart(j);                                           
                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition()))    // getting null here
                {
                    attachmentProcessing = true;
                    InputStream is;
                    is = part.getInputStream();
                    f = new File(filePath + part.getFileName());
                    fileArray.add(f);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while((bytesRead = is.read(buf))!=-1) {
                        fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    fos.close();
                }                                       
            }
        }
```

part details for mac mailing service:

> text/plain; charset=us-ascii
>   part.getDisposition() = null
>   multipart/mixed; boundary="Apple-Mail=_C50D7E2D-27A1-4449-BAA3-5DC9D1E522AF"

and for others

> multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0033_01D28DC6.C9D0C8B0"
>   text/plain; name=HashTagList.txt; charset=us-ascii
>   part.getDisposition() = attachment

Answer (score 1):

Disposition is optional; not all messages with "attachments" will set the disposition.  The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach) has more information.

Also, rather than checking for the string "multipart" in the content type, you should use the [isMimeType](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html#isMimeType-java.lang.String-) method and check for "multipart/mixed".

See the [msgshow.java](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) sample program for more examples and details.